# InitializeCriticalSectionEx Not Located In KERNEL32.Dll

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I am trying to build a dll project in VS2015 to deploy it on Windows XP. It works on Windows 7, but gives an error on Windows XP SP3:

> The procedure entry point InitializecriticalSectionEx could not be located in the dynaic link libray KERNEL32.dll

I have build the library with:
`Configuration=Release;Platform=x86;PlatformToolset=v140_xp;`

Unfortunatelly, the [`InitializeCriticalSectionEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683477%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function does not exist in the XP version of Kernel32.dll, even with SP3 installed. It was not introduced until Vista. It appears the driver you are using is not fully compatible with XP.

Is it possibible to solve this problem without downgrading the build PlatformToolset?

Comment: You should select xp toolkit.

Comment: It's not solvable as `InitializecriticalSectionEx` does not exist on Windows XP regardless of what toolkit you build with. Either use `InitializeCriticalSection` or use conditional compilation to build 2 dlls for deploying on older and newer platforms.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten yes, it is solvable, using dynamic loading instead of static linking

Answer (score 4):

Since you need your DLL to run on an OS where `InitializeCriticalSectionEx()` is not available, you cannot static link to the function at compile time.  That is why you are getting the entry point error.

Instead, you will have to load the `InitializeCriticalSectionEx()` function dynamically at runtime using [`GetProcAddress()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress) (or the [linker's delay-load feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls), which uses `GetProcAddress()` internally).

If the `InitializeCriticalSectionEx()` function fails to load at runtime, your code can then fallback to something else, like [`InitializeCriticalSection()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializecriticalsection) or even [`InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializecriticalsectionandspincount).

Comment: Instead of calling InitializeCriticalSection as a fallback, he could call InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount. It at least allows setting the spin count if that's desired.