# Crypto++ on Windows XP

Tags: c++, windows, windows-xp, crypto++

I am trying to build Crypto++ and target Windows XP. Reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp?view=msvc-160), I made these changes before building the library:

- Platform Toolset = Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)
  [image: Platform Toolset = Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)]
- Predefine macros WINVER=0x0501 and _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501
  [image: WINVER=0x0501]

Then I compiled some code (with the same changes as before for XP compatibility):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <cryptopp/cryptlib.h>
#include <cryptopp/blake2.h>


int main() {
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    BLAKE2b hash;
    std::string password = "hunter1";
    hash.Update((const byte*)password.data(), password.size());

    std::string digest;
    digest.resize(hash.DigestSize());
    
    hash.Final((byte*)&digest[0]);

    printf("Message: %s\n", password.c_str());
    puts("Digest:");

    for (char ch : digest)
        printf("%02hhX", ch);

    putchar('\n');
}
```

This works fine on Windows 10, but when I copy the `Release` directoty to Windows XP for testing, I get this error:

[image]]

So, what am I doing wrong, and how can I use this library on Windows XP, if at all?

Comment: Install vmware and run windows 10 inside of it.

Comment: @Hi-IloveSO I need to target Windows XP, not Windows 10 running in a VM.

Comment: [InitializeCriticalSectionEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializecriticalsectionex) does not exist on Windows XP. You can (only) link to it dynamically as described under [InitializeCriticalSectionEx Not Located In KERNEL32.Dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791834/initializecriticalsectionex-not-located-in-kernel32-dll), though there are additional complications if it's used by the library code.

Comment: @dxiv it is used by the Crypto++ library, so I can't fallback on `InitializeCriticalSection` as described in the answer you linked. That seems to mean that the library probably doesn't support XP.

Comment: cryptopp doesn't seem to use [InitializeCriticalSectionEx](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/search?q=InitializeCriticalSectionEx)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709094/c-application-built-with-120-xp-toolset-on-windows-xp-initializecriticalsecti

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili There is something fishy about this. WinSDK 7.1 `winbase.h` declares `InitializeCriticalSectionEx` conditional on `#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0403)` but the API is only documented to exist in Vista and later i.e. `>= 0x600`. Though there is also a `#define CRITICAL_SECTION_NO_DEBUG_INFO  RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_FLAG_NO_DEBUG_INFO` which would suggest some sort of forwarding, though I haven't followed it through all the way.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you very much. Making the runtime library dynamic for CryptoPP (/MD) fixed the issue. I guess this can be closed as a duplicate of the question you linked.